# Rolling count pandas for categorical variables using time

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Datetime   | Category | ID
--------------------------
2020-01-30 | A        | 1
2020-02-01 | B        | 1
2020-02-02 | A        | 1
2020-02-20 | A        | 1
2020-01-28 | B        | 2
2020-01-29 | C        | 2
2020-01-30 | C        | 2
2020-01-31 | D        | 2
2020-02-01 | D        | 2
2020-02-02 | D        | 2
2020-02-03 | C        | 2
```

I would like to obtain the top 2 most frequent categories for each ID within a 1 week window of the row (excluding the current row). Is that possible in pandas? I tried to do .rolling and .value_counts but it doesnt seem to work. Thanks!

Below is the dataframe which I would like to get:

```
Datetime   | Category | ID
--------------------------
2020-01-30 | NaN      | 1
2020-02-01 | [A, ""]  | 1
2020-02-02 | [A, B]   | 1
2020-02-20 | NaN      | 1
2020-01-28 | Nan      | 2
2020-01-29 | [B,""]   | 2
2020-01-30 | [B,C]    | 2
2020-01-31 | [B,C]    | 2
2020-02-01 | [C,D]    | 2
2020-02-02 | [C,D]    | 2
2020-02-03 | [C,D]    | 2
```

Thank you!

**Edit**
The pd.get_dummies answer is great but as my dataset is huge, it is not efficient. Would really appreciate if anyone has an efficient solution for this! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `resample()` rather than `rolling()`, because your time index frequency is daily and you want weekly stats, so try something like this:

```
df.groupby('ID').resample('1w').apply(lambda s: s.value_counts().head(2))
```

Note that this only works in versions of Pandas where `apply()` strips the data into `pd.Series`, not `np.arrays`. Also if you have more columns in your dataframe it may be necessary to specify the column name in the lambda functions, ie.:

```
df.groupby('ID').resample('1w').apply(lambda s: s['Category'].value_counts().head(2))
```

And if you need to exclude the first row in the window use `iloc[]` slicing:

```
df.groupby('ID').resample('1w').apply(lambda s: s['Category'].iloc[1:].value_counts().head(2))
```

Comment: thank you so much! but as some of my data is actually my frequency is not consistent (like ID 1 could have rows of data with more than 2 weeks apart), I would not be able to use shift in this case right?

Comment: Shift will work regardless of the inconsistencies in the index - it will just move all rows by 1. However if you have such big gaps it may cause some issues in the results.

Comment: OK, maybe `shift` was a bad idea. I made a change.

Comment: thanks for the clarifications! tried to implement this but I am getting the error: AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndexResamplerGroupby' object has no attribute 'value_counts' when I try to do the .apply

Comment: Which version of Pandas do you have installed? Mine is 1.0.3. You have to upgrade to the version that supports series inside apply(). I wrote that in the answer.

Comment: Yupp, I checked the version. Mine is 1.03 as well.

Comment: Do you specify the column? Ie. `s['Category']...`

Comment: yupp did the exact same one as yours hmm

Comment: If you are getting such error it means the object you are calling the `value_counts()` method is not `pd.Series`. You can verify it with `type` by: `df.groupby('ID').resample('1w').apply(type)` or `df.groupby('ID').resample('1w').apply(lambda s: type(s['Category']))`